# in react ag-grid table , how to prevent a dropdown component from collapsing when user selects an option and open a sub-grid on selecting an option

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

In react ag-grid table , I want to use Custom Dropdown component for a particular column and on selecting options from that dropdown, I want to prevent dropdown from collapsing and I want to show another flyout table on select of any option from dropdown and then select a row from that flyout table to populate the parent grid/column.For eg - Initial values in my dropdown component will be author like ['John', 'Jason'] now on select of suppose John, below is the expectation : Dropdown should not collapse after selecting John and On selecting John another sub-grid should open which should have details like - Author's Full Name and ProfessionNow after selecting any row from this sub-grid , Author's full name should get set in the original field .

Even after I tried using event.stopPropagation, my dropdown component is getting collapsed as soon as I select any option

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.